# Prove that every ball of radius r lies inside a box all of whose sides has length at most 2r. Prove that every bounded set lies inside a box.

Tags: analysis

Need to prove that every ball of radius $r$ lies inside a box all of whose
sides has length at most $2r$. Also need to prove that every bounded set lies inside a box.

I know that a ball of radius $r$ around a point $x$ which is an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the set $B_r(x)$
of all points of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of distance less than $r$ from $x$.

I also know that a box is defined as a product of closed intervals.

Comment: Try drawing a picture for both questions, it might help you see what inequality you need to show for the first one, and how big to make the box for your second one.

Comment: Will try that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first simplification is to consider $r=1$. The second simplification is to consider $n=2$, and the third, $x=0$. So, what's the box of side-length $2$ containing the unit ball, i.e. unit disk, in $\Bbb{R}^2$? For this one, you can just draw a picture.

Increasing the dimension is probably the apparently trickiest bit. But the reason you could put the unit disk $D^2$ into the square (spoilers!) $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ is that $\inf\{x:(x,y)\in D^2\}=\inf\{x:(x,y)\in D^2\}-1$, and similarly for the suprema in each coordinate. In other words, for every $(x,y)\in D^2, -1\leq x\leq 1$ and $-1\leq y \leq 1$. But that's saying exactly that $D^2\subseteq [-1,1]\times [-1,1]$! In almost exactly the same way you can get
$B_1(0)\subseteq [-1,1]^n$ for every $n$. Now can you generalize to all $r$ and $x$?

Once you've finished this, there's nothing to your second question: a bounded set is by definition one that lies in a ball, and you'll have just shown that every ball lies in a box, even with a very explicit bound on the size of the box.